# OUTPUT textbox to a window

Tags: python

I tried  to execute the following code in my system, and the window does not respond if  the submit button is clicked

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
top=Tk()
text=Text(top)
def onsubmit():
        a=v.get()
        ea.textbox(text=a)

v=StringVar()
t=Entry(top, textvariable=v)
submit=Button(top,text="SUBMIT",command=onsubmit)
t.grid(row=0,column=0)
submit.grid(row=0,column=1)
text.grid(row=1,column=0)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: variable `ea` seems to be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your script from terminal or just look at the text output of your program in some other way you will see the following error (just after pressing the button):

```
NameError: global name 'ea' is not defined
```

The error is on the second line of `onsubmit` function. Here is the working version:

```
def onsubmit():
    a=v.get()
    text.insert(INSERT, a)
```